# Using process builder to open a file in internet explorer Java

Tags: java, processbuilder

I have a program I have written for Java at work that takes an XML and allows users to view the XML in table form, make changes, then save the table as a new XML.

Everything is finished except one small detail. Once the user saves the table the data is of course parsed into a new XML. I then want a dialog to appear that tells the user the save location and asks if they would like to open the file.

If the user clicks yes then I want the XML to open in Internet Explorer. I had successfully implemented a similar approach with ProcessBuilder in another program but in that case the file needed to open with Notepad which worked perfectly.

Now the issue I'm having is that while InternetExplorer will open the file will not open, the browser will just stay on the home page. I'll post my code below if anyone can help me I'd greatly appreciate it!

```
location = "//CamT54Revised"+date+".xml";
            location = fHandling.saveFile.getSelectedFile()+location;

            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(location));
            transformer.transform(source, result);

            int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Output file saved as "+location+". Would you like to view the file?","Display Output",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if(dialogResult==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){

                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe", location);
                try{
                    pb.start();
                }catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
```

Comment: Windows doesn't use forward slashes (`//`), so the `location` value is not understood by IE. Why is it even starting with `//` in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that Internet Explorer is the default browser, you can use Desktop API for that matter.

```
public class DesktopTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        if (!Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            System.err.println("Desktop not supported!");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        File file = new File(args[0]);

        if (desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.OPEN)) {
            try {
                desktop.open(file);
            }
            catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.err.println("Unable to open: " + file.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But if you want to actually force Internet Explorer, then you will probably have to resort to your process builder anyways.

Comment: I do need to force Internet Explorer. If I use this approach it will open with Notepad which is useless because it won't be in a format that is easy to read. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `ProcessBuilder`, I would recommend you use [`Desktop.open(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open-java.io.File-) which *launches the associated application to open the file.* Something like,

```
File f = new File(location);
Desktop.open(f);
```

Comment: I believe OP's real problem is the `//` at the beginning of the `location` value, but I agree that this is the better way to "open the file", as OP called it. +1 Processing the `location` value through a `File` object will convert the `//` to `\\ `, but `\\filename` is not a valid path in Windows, so likely won't work either.

Comment: Andreas - If what you are saying is true then how come when I use "C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe" the internet explorer still opens? (Just not with my file). 

The problem with your suggestion Elliott is that I need to FORCE internet explorer to open the file, otherwise the file will just open with notepad and it won't be in a format that the user could understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec("C:\\path\\to\\notepad.exe C:\\path\\to\\file.txt");
```

First path is program in which you want open second path - specific file